# can we run/install macro in without macro enabled files (pptx)?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I wrote some macro of PowerPoint. Now if I want to run these macros, I need to save my PowerPoint as pptm file. It is kind of matter, as I need to save the final file as pptx not pptm.  Is there any way, I can install or run my macro to pptx files? I mean could I install my macro as an add-in, and it is working in pptx file.

If the way works, I can save my macro template powerpoint as pptx,
that is easier and more convenient.

Thanks,

Comment: Not possible. Your best bet is a VSTO add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an application add-in which would allow the Public procedures within it to be available independently of the PowerPoint file(s) you are working on in any given session. You could optionally add controls to a custom ribbon tab by editing the fluent UI XML of the file (I have some articles on Stack Exchange to show you how) and link those to your macros.

To create an add-in, save the .pptm file as a .ppam file (the folder location will change accordingly). Then in PowerPoint, assuming you have the Developer tab enabled, you can click Add-Ins and load your add-in from there. If the Developer tab isn't enabled, you need to go into the Backstage by clicking File then Options to add add-is.

To make sure the add-in loads automatically each time PowerPoint starts you can add code to the Auto_Open macro to add the two relevent registry keys (add-in Path and AutoLoad flag) or do this manually using regedit.exe. If you are deploying to many machines, the add-in can be wrapped in a setup.exe or setup.msi package but that is another topic.

Comment: Hi JamieG, thanks a lot for your answer. Good to know that we can run macro without enable file.  And could share the links about your articles?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think so there is anyway to run macro without enabling it.

But Alternate solution can be to.

Save the main file as .pptx and you can have another file as .pptm you just need to add sub to open the .pptx or main file and perform the macro fuctions from there

In this way your macros file and .pptx are seperate and you can achieve what you are trying to do via the .pptm files.

Hope this helps.